# A Jacobian of the Cayley graph

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, topological-groups

Let $\pi$ be a finitely generated discrete group. Let $F$ be a finitely generated free group with an epimorphism to $\pi$. Let $K$ be the kernel of the epimorphism. Consider the Abelianization of $K$. This is an infinitely generated free Abelian group. Let $T$ be the Pontryagin dual, which is an infinite-dimensional torus (something like a Jacobian of the Cayley graph). The group $\pi$ acts on it. Did anybody study such a thing?

Comment: I'm not aware of any literature on its Pontryagin dual, but the abelianization of $K$ is called the *relation module* of the finitely generated group $\pi$.  It is a module over $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$, and has a large literature (though in general it is hard to work with).

Comment: As a random example of something that is known about this, the Lyndon Identity Theorem says that the relation module of a one-relator group is cyclic; see Theorem 6.2 of my notes on one-relator group (see https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/OneRelator.pdf) for more details.